# Linear resource modeling with greater than zero coefficients as constraint

Tags: regression, linear, regression-coefficients, constraint

I am doing a modeling for CPU usage in a system. I would like to infer the cost of each transaction type flowing through the system. I have total of 23 transaction types, and each transaction type has its own count. The data is collected for a period of 3 months with one hour interval. The restriction is the cost of the transaction should not be <= 0. I tried out several models, some either gave negative coefficients (for example lm in R), or some gave too many zeroes (for example nnls in R). Hence, the prediction results are not good. The objective is be able to infer the CPU cost through coefficient, and also be able to use the cost to predict the CPU usage. I am wondering if there is a model that I can use to restrict the coefficients greater than zero. Any insight?

Comment: What's your left hand side variable? What's the exact regression you're running?

Comment: It sounds like an issue you may be having is that certain transaction types predict that the system *isn't* under load? Eg. if someone orders a ham sandwich, it may predict the restaurant is in the lunch hour crush but if someone orders dessert wine, it predicts the restaurant is at the end of dinner service and the load is winding down?

Comment: My left hand side variable is CPU consumption.

Comment: Each observation is a point in time? Eg. you observe $y_t$ every 10 seconds?

Comment: The CPU consumption is also collected at the same interval. During busy hour interval, we have higher CPU consumption with higher different count of transactions. And it is reverse during non busy hour.

Comment: The point in time is every hour